# React Native: Can't see changes to my code

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm a beginner with React Native. I've followed the simple tutorial from the offical doc, but I have a problem when I try to see my code changes. The doc says:

> For Android, you can edit index.android.js to make changes to the app
>   and press Reload JS from the rage shake menu to see the changes

I'm developing directly on my Nexus 6, not on the simulator, I did as it tells but I can't see any changes for my Android sample app, I've tried only to edit the text but without success. I've also tried to rebuild after any changes but no result, I'm sure it's a simple thing but what am I missing?

Comment: I am having the same problem. The JS bundle is loaded ok without errors (I've added the dev server IP:port in the dev setting of the app). But if I make changes to the code and request a JS Reload from the app, the bundle is loaded but everything looks the same. I believe this may have to do with the file watcher and the cached files on Windows. Anyone?

Comment: I've solved simply working on Mac... Too many problems on win

Comment: Good for you. But that does not solve the problem. It seems the issue is to do with the MAX_WAIT_TIME used by the FileWatcher (NodeWatcher on Windows, WatchMan on Mac) when crawling all folders to be watched. If the timeout is reached, no errors are reported to the user, and changes to the js files will not be picked up by the Packager. A possible solution could be to listen to the change events emitted by FileWatcher before the crawling job is finished. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6674  to follow on this

Comment: Yes it isn't the solution, I was simply bored :P But I didn't see this issue, I'll check it, thank you man!

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue and I finally found one solution that worked for me.

https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/381#issuecomment-257669560

Just run these commands

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist
watchman version
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 3):

Run your code from terminal with the following command

**mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
react-native run-android**

this will refresh your code changes.

Answer (score 0):

From React-Native Docs - http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html

**Configure your app to connect to the local dev server via Wi-Fi**

1. Make sure your laptop and your phone are on the same Wi-Fi network.
2. Open your React Native app on your device. You can do this the same way you'd open any other app.
3. You'll see a red screen with an error. This is OK. The following steps will fix that.

> 4. Open the Developer menu by shaking the device or running adb shell input keyevent 82 from the command line.

5. Go to Dev Settings.
6. Go to Debug server host for device.
7. Type in your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server (e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081). On Mac, you can find the IP address in System Preferences / Network. On Windows, open the command prompt and type ipconfig to find your machine's IP address (more info).

> 8. Go back to the Developer menu and select Reload JS.

Comment: I've tried to follow this steps but I get a red screen "Unable to download JS Bundle"

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a physical device, use:

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

And then rerun

```
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.